# how to make a grid column editable when using custom store

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I want to be able to edit grid colums inline as it is shown in a simple grid example in AppSDK docs
https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/example/Grid
but it looks like that this functionality is not available by default if when a custom store is used:

```
_createGrid: function(stories) {
     this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: stories,
            pageSize: 100
        }),
        columnCfgs: [
            {
               text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
            },
            {
                text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            //other columns...
        ]
    });
}
```

In my app when I click on the Name the field does not become editable as it is in the simple grid example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be modified as follows to add inline edit capability:
set editor to 'textfield' for the Name column, set grid's selType to  'cellmodel', and instantiate CellEditing plugin.

```
_createGrid: function(stories) {
         this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: stories,
                pageSize: 100
            }),
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', editor: 'textfield'
                }
        //other columns...
            ],
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1
                })
            ]

        });
    }
```

Please see documentation on Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing [here](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing)